# PyInstaller - How do you handle environmental variables?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

**Background:**

I am trying to convert a python script to an executable file that can be used on other computers. I decided to use PyInstaller. I am using *Python 2.7.13*/*Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)*. I have of course seen many examples and I can achieve this for basic examples. However, the script I am now working on uses environmental variables. The following block of code appears at the start of my python script:

```
import os
# force qt4
os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'qt4'
os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyqt'

from traits.api import HasTraits, Range, Instance, Button, on_trait_change, Bool, Str, Enum, Float, Int
from traitsui.api import View, Item, Group, HGroup, spring, Handler, Action, InstanceEditor, Menu, MenuBar, message, \
    Tabbed
from mayavi.core.ui.api import MayaviScene, SceneEditor, MlabSceneModel
from pyface.api import FileDialog, OK
import yaml
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np
from collections import namedtuple
import gdal
```

**Problem:**

Running `pyinstaller --onefile filename.py` on the command line produces an `.exe`, but it doesn't run because of the error: `ImportError: No module named qt4`."qt4" isn't a module, so I am assuming the problem is with the line " `os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'qt4`'".
 After looking at various questions related to PyInstaller, I know how to use 'hiddenimports', but I have no idea how to handle environmental variables. Obviously something like `pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import qt4 filename.py` didn't work.

Comment: What is os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] used for ? I would guess that it is used by one of the imported modules to import a toolkit, ie qt4 in this case. Did you install qt4 ?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should try `pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import "os" filename.py`